How to upload Excel/CSV file to s3 using rest assured
I reads many docs that suggest me to use multipart, but I still got 403 status code.
Here is my code:
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src/main/java/assets/status.xlsx");

Map<String, String> data = table_data.asMap(String.class, String.class);
path = (String.format("schemas/api_core/s3/token/get.json")).replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "_param");
context.session.put("endpoint", "s3/token");
context.session.put("baseURI", env("URL_BACKOFFICE"));

JSONObject queryParams = new JSONObject(String.format("{\"acl\": \"private\"}"));
String jsonString = queryParams.toString();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
paramsMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);

Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + ApiData.getAccessToken());
headers.put("X-Secure-Key", ApiData.getSecureKey());

RequestSpecification getRequest = context.requestSetup().headers(headers);
getRequest.queryParams(paramsMap);
context.response = getRequest.when().get(context.session.get("endpoint").toString());
Response response = context.response;
validateRequest(data, response, path);
JsonNode resData = objectMapper.readTree(response.getBody().asString()).get("data");
if (Objects.equals(response.getStatusCode(), 200)) {
    ApiData.setAwsKey(String.valueOf(resData.get("AWSAccessKeyId")));
    ApiData.setRedirectLink(String.valueOf(resData.get("success_action_redirect")));
    ApiData.setPolicy(String.valueOf(resData.get("policy")));
    ApiData.setSignature(String.valueOf(resData.get("signature")));
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/";

    String contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    String filename = "status.xlsx";

    context.response = RestAssured.given()                 .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
            .multiPart("key", "excel-import-kyc/status.xlsx")
            .multiPart("AWSAccessKeyId", ApiData.getAwsKey())
            .multiPart("acl", "private")
            .multiPart("success_action_redirect", ApiData.getRedirectLink())
            .multiPart("policy", ApiData.getPolicy())
            .multiPart("Signature", ApiData.getSignature())
            .multiPart("Content-Type", contentType)
            .multiPart("file", file)
            .multiPart("region", "ap-southeast-1")
            .multiPart("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com")
            .header("Content-Type", contentType)
            .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
            .expect()
            .statusCode(303)
            .when()
            .post();

I have search may docs and many suggest me with encoder. I already use id and still got 403.
How to upload/import Excel/CSV file to s3 using rest assured.
